# Objective-C Frameworks Visibility of Classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

In my iOS App I have different Framework Targets (Kit, Data, Entity) with the following (intended) dependency graph:

```
App -> Kit
Data -> Kit
Data -> Entity
Kit -> Entity
```

In the App Target configuration I do not link against `Entity` but it is still possible to import classes from Entity within a `App` class:

```
#import <Entity/Entity.h>
```

How can I prevent that I use `Entity` classes in my App Target?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom script that runs with each compile. (Build phases)

This script can recursively check if you have this text in a file

```
#import <Entity/Entity.h>
```

and it can also generate compilation errors.

Here is something to start from:

Go to your project->target->build phases-> "+"

```
TAGS="Entity/Entity"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.*" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ error: \$1/"
```

(this script needs a bit of tailoring for your case)

[Some example](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/better-build-phase-scripts/)

Comment: thx. this solution would work but feels like a workaround for the work I would expect the compiler / linker should do.

Comment: This cannot be done at a compiler lever in this technology from what I know. The compilation rules are 'already set'/predefined, maybe they support some custom functionality added for these scenarios but I don't feel it's the compiler's job to understand what your code should or should not use.